# MySQL storing bar codes - optimisation

Tags: php, mysql

I need store bar codes for reference of products.

I 'm stuck into optimisation, currenty I have two ideas into my mind but can't figure out on my own which goes better in the long run.

[image]

Note. Tables can get more or less large, about 200k records

How would you tackle this task?

Comment: How can multiple products have the same barcode?

Comment: it's not a product actually, it's smth like characteristic of the product. Multiple products share this general characteristic. Often situation when the same product has different expire date, in this case all these products share one codebase_product and it contains barcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't see your point of separating the bar code from the product table. it doesn't need to be a primary key, it doesn't need to be unique, it just remains an attribute of the product. If you can have multiple bar codes by product, scenario one may be a thing (but it would not be efficient in the case of multiple products having the same barcode), but scenario 2 is just not necessary in any way.